# Restore the distribution database to production database

Tags: sql-server, replication

I was trying to set up my SQL server for replication. I accidentally added my production database as the distribution database. Is there any way to revert the changes without losing any data in the database?

Comment: Restore from backup

Comment: I accidentally added my production database as the distribution database- can you explain more? When you mark a database as a distributor many system objects get created automatically to support replication (the kind you are deploying). I am not aware of a way to convert a distribution database to a user database cleanly.